# The type or namespace name 'FtpWebRequest' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, dll

в программе использую такие библиотеки:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
```

Но почему-то не могу объявить `FtpWebRequest` , говорит что `could not be found` , хотя в `ObjectBrowser` есть. Что делать? Может как-то явно объявить?

Мой код:

```
private void buttonSetting_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        // Get the object used to communicate with the server.
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://www.contoso.com/test.htm");
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

        // This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential ("anonymous","janeDoe@contoso.com");

        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
        Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());

        Console.WriteLine("Download Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription);

        reader.Close();
        response.Close();  

    }
```

## Дополнение

Использую версию студии: `Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 v.9.0` `Microsoft .NET Framework Version 3.5 SP1`

Из референсов `System` не удален.

## Дополнение 2

Мой проект не `WinForm` , а `SmartDevice` . Может это как-то влияет? Но мне нужен именно `SmartDevice`

Всё еще нуждаюсь в помощи.

Comment: Приведите минимальный код, который выдает у вас ошибку. using-и - это не подключения библиотек, и они не имеют отношения к проблеме.

Comment: FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://site"); здесь FtpWebRequest не работает, а WebRequest работает. Также FtpWebResponse не работает.

Comment: @Roman В вопрос это надо добавлять. Вам пишут комментарии чтобы вы сформулировали вопрос более понятно. Понятно?

Comment: @Cerbo да. Добавил код в вопрос.

Comment: @Roman если создать новый проект WinForms, вписать ваши usings - то код из вашего примера компилируется. Вы под какую версию фреймворка проект собираете (в какой версии студии)? Не под 1.1 случайно?

Comment: А вы случаем System из референсов не удалили?

Comment: Вопрос всё еще не решен)

Comment: @Roman вопрос не решен, потому что вы не отвечаете на комментарии. Вас же спрашивали про версию фреймворка и версию студии.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FtpWebRequest нет в стандартной библиотеке под WinCE. А у вас, [судя по всему](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/438420/you-must-add-reference/438425#438425), именно WinCE. Ищите сторонние реализации.