# You must add reference

Tags: c#, .net, dll

Скачал себе вот эту [библиотеку](http://enterprisedt.com/products/edtftpnet/)

Установил её, и всё вроде бы хорошо, но когда нажимаю `Debug` , то вылетает с такой ошибкой:

> **Error    1**
>
> The type 'System.ComponentModel.Component' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.
>
> You must add a reference to assembly 'System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
>
> Z:\RF\Программы для Терминалов\TRF(FTP download) — копия\TRF\MainForm.cs
>
> 56 13  TRF

Судя по ошибке мне нужно добавить библиотеку `System`, но она у меня уже есть, и я могу в `ObjectBrowser` найти `System.ComponentModel.Component`.

Вот скриншот, на котором видно что библиотека есть в `reference`[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Редакция `edtFTPnet/Free` не включает в себя сборку для Windows CE, и не может быть использованна для данной платформы.

Используйте платную `edtFTPnet/Compact`, либо откажитесь от использования данной библиотеки в своём проекте.